# Django DateField greater than filtering not working

Tags: django

What could possibly cause this?

```
(Pdb) Incident.objects.filter(incident_date__gt=curr_date)[0].incident_date
datetime.date(2019, 7, 19)
(Pdb) curr_date
datetime.date(2017, 7, 26)
```

Seems like the greater-than is just not working here.

My model:

```
class Incident(models.Model):                                                                                           
    incident_dt = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)                                                           
    incident_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Dates in 2019 are greater than 2017. Looks right to me.

Comment: Doh! Totally didn't see that, thanks for lending a pair of eyes. I should probably delete this since it's likely unhelpful for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed correct, didn't see the year as 2019 for the first value!